# Packaging an Orchard module with complex external assembly dependencies

Tags: module, orchardcms

Using orchard 1.3.9 I made a simple HelloWorld module.

That module has a reference to an external assembly: Library1.

On the other hand, Library1 has a reference to Library2.

(Library2 is not referenced directly by HelloWorld module).

When I create a package for this module using the command line tool, I can see that the package contains only Library1.

Therefore, the module won't work properly on the target Orchard site.

What is the correct procedure to make sure the package includes all libraries needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include your dependencies for example in a libraries folder in the module, then reference them from your project file. They will then get included in the package. You can look at the Vandelay.Industries module for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Bertrand's answer solved the problem, but I would like to leave here some additional information:

- The "Libraries" folder must exists in the projects's folder, but should **not** be included in the Visual Studio project. Otherwise the package creation will fail (see here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/264471)
- The Module must reference all assemblies, even if they are not needed directly; using the example of the question, the HellowWorld project must reference both "Library1" and "Library2", even if "Library2" is not used directly by "HelloWorld"